# How can I save the data of a document but changing one of the values

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Using this I use the id of the document to identify the document that I want to modify but what if want to use a value inside of that document instead? For example:

```
dbUserDoc.collection('shoplist').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            // ignore: avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
              final docPro = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('products')
                  .doc(result.id); //here i use the document id but i want to use a value inside of that document
              print(result.id);
              docPro.get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                final int stockInt =
                    data['stock'] - int.parse(result['quantity']);
                final stock = <String, int>{"stock": stockInt};
                docPro.set(stock, SetOptions(merge: true));
              });
            })
          });
```

[image: example]

Comment: Well it would be simple, just use where, it may be necessary to create an indexes. Test the where in the firestore queryBuilder. `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: 'JxnUNcBOtRJw1N12p7yg')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the value of the `id` field inside of the `products` document, you can do:

```
final product = result.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(product["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `result` object is an object of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html). If you want to display the value of a field, not the value of the document ID, which in your case are the same, then please use:

```
print(result["id"]);
```

This means that you'll print the value of the `id` field that exists inside the document.

Comment: Hey Willders. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?